# Как реализовать идентификацию пользователя в микросервесе

Tags: java, spring, oauth2, микросервисы, keycloak

У меня есть потребность идентифицировать пользователя в микросервисах
Я использую keycloak для auth2 авторизации
Gateway решает нужно ли авторизоваться или нет
Но что делать с идентификацией после gateway
Делать сущность user на каждом микросервисе?
Я использую java spring, как мне получить заветный Authentication?
Буду благодарен за любую наводку или объяснения

Я пробовал реализовать аутентификацию на каждом микросервисе, но подозреваю, что это неправильный подход